# How can i send back the ether which i used to buy a token in ERC20?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, erc20, ether

Iam trying to write method in solidity where it checks if the given ether is enough to buy my coin. If its enough I will give them the respective amount of coins but if the ether is not enough I need to send back the ether which is getting used to buy a coin. Is there any method to do that ?

This is the method i have written to buy a coin.

```
function buyTokens(uint256 noOfCoins) public payable returns (bool success){
    if(CoinValue*noOfCoins <= msg.value)
    {
        balances[msg.sender] += noOfCoins;
        return true;
    }
    else{

        emit TokenIssues("You doesnt have enough balances to purchase these quartz base coins");
        msg.sender.transfer(msg.value);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: apart from your actual problem i find 2 issues with your method. **1.** you can't return any value from a function that changes the state of your contract. **2.** If a user accidentally sends excess `ether` to buy your token, you are keeping it and not refunding the excess `ether`

Answer (score 0):

If the **msg.value** is lower then the amount you are expecting just **throw** in the else clause.
That way the ether will be returned to the user.

Comment: `throw` is **deprecated** in `Solidity 0.5.x`

Comment: Then he simple use **require** to check his condition.